# Filter and Match Column on a List of Substrings

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am attempting to filter a table of user actions on a list of specific actions. For example, given the following data

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| UserId | UserAction                                                   |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12345  | Account Creation Successful                                  |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 23456  | Attempt to create duplicate account with email abc@email.com |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 34567  | Account Creation Unuccessful                                 |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 45678  | Attempt to create duplicate account with email xyz@email.com |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 56789  | Email Sent                                                   |
+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want all rows where the `UserAction` contains the strings "Account Creation" or "Attempt to create duplicate account".

I was able to achieve this with the following Linq, but the query's performance caused the webpage to timeout and blocked other queries to the table.

```
var actions = new HashSet<string>
{
    "Account Creation",
    "Attempt to create duplicate account"
};

using (var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var logs = databaseContext.Actions.Where(log => actions.Any(a => log.UserAction.Contains(a)));
}
```

To optimize this, I wanted to use an entirely SQL solution. One way of doing so could be using multiple

```
WHERE [UserAction] LIKE 'Account Creation%' OR [UserAction] LIKE 'Attempt to create duplicate account%' OR...
```

but I need to filter on many different actions, not just the two in this example, causing too long of a query with multiple `OR LIKE` statements.

Finally, I would like to use something similar to

```
WHERE [UserAction] IN ('Account Creation', 'Attempt to create duplicate account')
```

but the problem is the list contains substrings which will be found in the UserAction column. It would be great if I could use the entire UserAction string in the list used by the `IN` operator, but because some strings have variable data (like the email address), I need to match substrings.

So, what I am looking for is a way to achieve the hypothetical

```
WHERE ('Account Creation', 'Attempt to create duplicate account') IN [UserAction]
```

where a list of substrings can be matched on the values of a column in SQL.

Thanks for your time.

The following SQL can be used to reproduce the situation.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [MatchListOnList].[dbo].[Actions]

CREATE TABLE [MatchListOnList].[dbo].[Actions] (
    UserId varchar(16),
    UserAction varchar(128)
)

INSERT INTO [MatchListOnList].[dbo].[Actions] (
    UserId,
    UserAction
)
VALUES
(
    '12345',
    'Account Creation Successful'
),
(
    '23456',
    'Attempt to create duplicate account with email abc@email.com'
),
(
    '34567',
    'Account Creation Unsuccessful'
),
(
    '45678',
    'Attempt to create duplicate account with email xyz@email.com'
),
(
    '56789',
    'Email Sent'
),
(
    '67890',
    'Email Sent'
),
(
    '78901',
    'Email Sent'
)
```

Comment: The `IN` clause compares the values for equality. It doesn't do `Contains`operation.

Comment: How many items you have in `actions` collection?

Comment: Currently, there are 15 actions to filter on, but millions of records in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work; it no longer times out and doesn't block any other services.

I did this by building an SQL query and running it directly against the database.

```
var actions = new HashSet<string>
{
    "Account Creation",
    "Attempt to create duplicate account"
};

using (var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Actions] WHERE [UserAction] LIKE ";
    var queryStringActions = actions
        .Select(action => $"'{action}%'");

    query += $"{string.Join(" OR [UserAction] LIKE ", queryStringActions)}";

    var logs = databaseContext.Database.SqlQuery<Entities.Action>(query).AsQueryable();
}
```

The resulting SQL query is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Actions]
WHERE [UserAction] LIKE 'Account Creation%'
OR [UserAction] LIKE 'Attempt to create duplicate account%'
```

Comment: Note - if you want to support the possibility of varying numbers of `actions` you could also use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to build LINQ expressions dynamically while remaining strongly typed. Using string substitution instead of parameters to build SQL statements is bad idea, even when you are creating the strings.

Comment: Would it also be bad to type the entire string "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Actions] WHERE [UserAction] LIKE 'Account Creation%' OR [UserAction] LIKE 'Attempt to create duplicate account%'" directly into the `Database.SqlQuery()` method? I understand using parameters is good protection against injection attacks but I do not see the difference in this case.

Comment: Well, that depends on potential future maintainers of the code. I think it is slightly better to type the literal SQL string because anyone would have to know they need to properly escape the string values in a SQL statement, whereas they may not realize how they need to handle the array initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `||` in LINQ:

```
using (var databaseContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var logs = databaseContext.Actions.Where(log => log.UserAction.Contains("Account Creation") ||
                                                    log.UserAction.Contains("Attempt to create duplicate account"));
}
```

To be more specific, you could use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains` in LINQ. It will translate to SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The SQL generated by this is similar to using multiple "OR LIKE 'Action%'" statements. Do you know if this is the most optimal query to filter the results?

Comment: @SpencerStream That really depends on your SQL engine. Some engines will use indexes since the prefix is fixed. You could possible check the plan for a similar manually entered query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table with all the string values that you want to filter on, and join on your `Actions` table using a `LIKE` operator with a wildcard. This should give you the same behavior in SQL as using the `CONTAINS` operator in LINQ.

```
CREATE TABLE ActionFilters (Action VARCHAR(128))
INSERT INTO dbo.ActionFilters
(
    Action
)
VALUES
('Attempt to create duplicate account'),
('Account Creation')

SELECT a.UserId,
       a.UserAction
FROM Actions a
INNER JOIN ActionFilters f
    ON a.UserAction LIKE f.Action + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this solution because it better follows relational database design. Unfortunately, it does not perform as well as using multiple "OR LIKE 'Action%'" statements.